# How can I avoid `#pragma once in main file` in GCC when using precompiled headers?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning, precompiled-headers

Here is a minimal example:

```cpp
// pch.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
```

And I run:

```sh
g++ -x c++-header -o pch.h.gch -c pch.hpp
```

When I run the command, I get

```
pch.h:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
    1 | #pragma once
      |
```

From my understanding, this behavior is intended by GCC after reading their bugzilla bug tracker; so, this is not a bug but a feature.

How can I disable this warning? Is there a warning number or name that I can suppress by adding it as a pragma statement:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcan-i-set-something-here"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From my understanding, this behavior is intended by GCC

As far as I can tell, it's a bug.

> How can I disable this warning?

Unfortunately, it appears that you cannot since the warning cannot be controlled by an option. In my opinion, this is a bug as well.

You can circumvent the issue by using a header guard instead of `#pragma once`.